# How can I exported a type from a Vue 3 single file Typescript component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, vuejs3

I have a type defined in one single file component that I would like to use in another component. However when I import that type there, Typescript claims the type is not exported and ESLint treats it `any`. Thus rules like `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment` are triggered. One workaround I found, is creating a `.d.ts` definition file of the same base file name as the component, but I would like my components to stay a single file.

Minimum (not) working example:

##### ExportingComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export type foo = { bar: () => void }

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ExportingComponent'
})
</script>

<style></style>
```

##### ImportingComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { foo } from './ExportingComponent'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ImportingComponent',

  setup () {
    // next line triggers @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
    const fooFoo = {} as Partial<foo>

    /* do something with fooFoo... */
 
    return {}
  }
})
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that in a newly scaffolded Vue CLI TypeScript project. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: Interesting note: the above seems to work with the latest version of Vue CLI and such. But that's because you're importing a type in a `.vue` file **into** _another_ `.vue` file. If you try to import from a `.vue` file into a `.ts` file, it still won't work.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1281

Answer (score 10):

Another way to handle this is using `<script setup>`, which allows you to also  [use a "normal" script tag](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script) in the same component.

```html
<!-- ExportingComponent.vue -->
<template>
  <div />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export type foo = { bar: () => void }
</script>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const someVar = ref(1)
</script>

<style></style>
```